# Difference between f.close(), f.close and f.closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-io, with-statement

```
with open('new.txt', 'r+') as f:
    print(f.readline())


if f.close:
    print('It is closed')
else:
    print('It is open.')
```

If I run this code, outputs `'It is closed'`. However, if I change the if statement from `f.close` to `f.closed()`, I get the output `'It is open'`. So is my file closed or open? Why am I getting different outputs?

Comment: Did you try `print(f.close)` and `print(f.closed())` and compare?

Comment: You are using `with open`, so you should not even be bothered with calling `.close`

Comment: @bereal the `print(f.close)` gives me `<built-in method close of _io.TextIOWrapper object at 0x0000020745364AC8>
` and the other shows the error saying `bool object is not callable`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`f.close` is a reference to the `close` method of the `file` object, so always evaluates as `True` when read as a boolean. `f.close()` is a call to that method, which does not return anything, so will always evaluate to `False`, as `bool(None)` evaluates to `False`. `f.closed` is a boolean attribute which tells us whether or not the file is closed. If you alter your code to:

```
if f.closed:
    print('It is closed')
else:
    print('It is open.')
```

This will return the result you expect. As you have used `with ... as f`, your file will be closed automatically after you leave the scope of that statement, so you don't have to worry about using `f.close()` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`f.close` is the function object, and as such using `if f.close` does not call the function.
`if f.close` thus always evaluates as True. Further, if the method did not exist, it would not return False, it would provide a syntax error.

```
>>> type(f.close)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> type(f.doesnotexist)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'doesnotexist'
```

You can check what `if f.close` will evaluate to by checking what the `bool(.)` function returns:

```
>>> bool(f.close)
True
```

From which we can see that this evaluates to true.

`f.closed` is the member that tells you whether your file has been closed (which `with` does automatically), `f.close()` closes your file.

`f.closed()` raises a TypeError, because `f.closed` is a boolean and thus can not be called:

```
>>> f.closed()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```